# The frequency of items in HashMaps

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have been trying to work out this code and I think there must be something I cannot see. Here are my class and its "add" function. The add is supposed to update the List and provide an information to the counter. Sadly, the HashMap doesn't respond whereas the List does. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
public class Basket {

private List<Product> products;
private HashMap<Product, Integer> counter;

public Basket(){
    products = new LinkedList<Product>();
    counter = new HashMap<Product, Integer>();
}

public void add(Product product){
    products.add(product);
    for(Product key : counter.keySet()){
        if(product.getName() != key.getName()){
            counter.put(product, 1);
        }else{
            counter.put(product, counter.get(product) +1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not compare `String`s with `==`, use the `equals` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues I see with your code

1) You're comparing Strings (the two product names) using != which isn't correct. You must use String.equals() or String.equalsIngoreCase()

2) You're also trying to increase the counter for the product each time you iterate through an element in the map. I'm pretty sure you only want to do this once.

With those fixes you could do something like this. (Note: I used a label in this solution but it functions the same way a boolean flag would. It just ensures that you have iterated through every element in the map and made sure the product doesn't exist before adding it)

```
    public void add(Product product) {
        products.add(product);
        add: {
            for (Product key : counter.keySet()) {
                if (key.getName().equals(product.getName())) {
                    counter.put(key, counter.get(key) + 1);
                    break add;
                }
            }
            counter.put(product, 1);
        }
    }
```

Ideally however, you would override the .equals() and .hashCode() methods in Product and then you would be able to use the HashMap.containsKey() method like this:

```
    public void add(Product product) {
        products.add(product);
        if (counter.containsKey(product)) {
            counter.put(product, counter.get(product) + 1);
        } else {
            counter.put(product, 1);
        }
    }
```

And that could also be further simplified using a ternary:

```
    public void add(Product product) {
        products.add(product);
        counter.put(product, counter.containsKey(product) ? counter.get(product) + 1 : 1);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do this - `if(product.getName() != key.getName())` in the loop and etc.

If all you want is to check if the `Product` already exists/not in the map-
 if no, add the product to the map, and set counter to 1, if yes increase the counter by  1.

You can do this:

```
if(counter.get(product) == null)
   counter.put(product,1);
else 
  counter.put(product, counter.get(product)+1);
```

The default hashCode() method of the `Product` class would ensure that it knows if it is a duplicate Product object that is being added.

The get() method would return the value of the `Key-Value` of the particular pair.

Comment: The return value will be null, not zero, if the product isn't in the map, and the second test is redundant.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the suggestions @EJP . I coded for a primitive 'int'.

Comment: When would `counter.get(product) == 0` ever?

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't make any sense. You're traversing the key set and if *any* key doesn't match you are adding the product. You don't need to traverse the map. Just look it up:

```
public void add(Product product){
    products.add(product);
    Integer count = counter,get(product);
    if (count == null) {
        counter.put(product, 1);
    }else{
        counter.put(product, count+1);
    }
}
```

NB Synchronization is also required.